# javascript add item to the begining of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have object array, which looks like

```
Object {0: "tariffs", 1: "tariffs_yes", 2: "tariffs_no"}
```

from chrome's console

And I need to unshift this array and add {-1: 'new item'} to the beginning of array. I can't use `array.unshift('newItem');` and `array[-1] = 'new item...'` adds item to the top of array:

```
Object {0: "tariffs", 1: "tariffs_yes", 2: "tariffs_no", -1: "new item..."}
```

How can I add to the beginning?

Comment: It should be noted, according to the specs, keys from an object have no order. Why can't you use an array?

Comment: You have an object, not an array

Comment: if `array.unshift()` isn't throwing error then data shown is not real representation of what you are working with. Trying to use it on that object would throw an error

Comment: There's no such thing as an "object array" either. It's either an object _or_ an array, and, as Thomas says, you're better off using an array `['tariffs', 'tariffs_yes', 'tarriffs_no']` for this. Using `unshift` will then work.

Comment: I got this object from `JSON.parse(response);` Should I convert all key/values to array or does JSON.parse have arguments for converting to array, not to object?

Comment: `var arr = Object.keys(response).map(function(key) { return response[key]; });`

Comment: thx. Will use this array.

Answer (score 0):

> And I need to unshift this array

It's not an array, it's an object.

> add `{-1: 'new item'}` to the beginning of array

Objects do not have beginnings and ends; they are just bags of key/value pairs.

You can add the property you want with

```
object[-1] = "new item";
```

Comment: I like the technical term "bags".

Answer (score 0):

You are using an object and treating it as an array. According to the [definition of an Object from ECMAScript Third Edition (pdf)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> 4.3.3 Object
>   An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.

To be able to create a sortable collection, use an array instead.